# jQuery Autcomplete - Error when user interacts with input box while request is still at server

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery Autocomplete version 1.2.9 that can be found at https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete. Here is my problem: if a user interacts with the input textbox while the autocomplete ajax request is at the server (hasnt received response), something in the javascript is throwing an error that is tough to track down. I noticed that while the ajax request is at the server, the input textbox loses focus. Maybe it has something to do with that?

I am currently working through this and I see that the error is an abort.

I am also trying to simple override the ajax call using this code but it doesn't seem to be correct:

```
$autocomplete.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: request,
            timeout: 200,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(2);
                //response(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert(1);
                response([]); // send no results to the widget.
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to be specific about the error and include the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I added the onSearchError option to the autocomplete setup to suppress the error:

```
$autocomplete.autocomplete({
    onSearchError: function() {
        // do nothing - suppress error
    }
});
```